# Node JS error crash after handling custom error

Tags: node.js, error-handling

the problem is the following. I'm using node js with express and mongo db for my backend. I'm new with node js so I will try to explain the problem.
I'm creating a endpoint to validate a confirmation code for emails validation and it's working fine when I found the problem doing a return and showing a code 200, but I want to display another error when is not found. So after try to validate a invalid code the backend crash and show the following error.

```
CONTROLLER
function confirmation(req, res, next) {
    userService.confirmate(req.body)
        .then (res.status(200).json({status:"ok"}))
        .catch(err => next(err));
}
```

```
SERVICE
async function confirmate(body) {
    User.findOneAndUpdate({token: body.code}, {$set: {isVerified: true}}, {upsert: false}, function(err,doc) {
        if (err) {
            // SOME ERROR
            console.log(' error');
            throw err; }

        if (!doc) {
            // NOT FOUND HANDLER
            console.log('not found);
            throw new Error('example')
        }
        // FOUNDED!
        console.log("Updated");
        return;
    });
}
```

```
ERROR HANDLER
module.exports = errorHandler;

function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
    if (typeof (err) === 'string') {
        // custom application error
        return res.status(400).json({ message: err });
    }

    if (err.name === 'ValidationError') {
        // mongoose validation error
        return res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
    }

    if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
        // jwt authentication error
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid Token' });
    }

    // default to 500 server error
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
}
```

```
ERROR
D:\DESARROLLO\menuon-project\be-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:132
      throw err;
      ^

Error: example
    at D:\DESARROLLO\menuon-project\be-server\users\user.service.js:88:23
    at D:\DESARROLLO\menuon-project\be-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4690:16
    at model.Query.Query._completeOne (D:\DESARROLLO\menuon-project\be-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1932:12)
    at cb (D:\DESARROLLO\menuon-project\be-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3285:11)
    at D:\DESARROLLO\menuon-project\be-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3376:14
    at D:\DESARROLLO\menuon-project\be-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4093:12
    at result (D:\DESARROLLO\menuon-project\be-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:414:17)
    at session.endSession (D:\DESARROLLO\menuon-project\be-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:401:11)
    at ClientSession.endSession (D:\DESARROLLO\menuon-project\be-server\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\sessions.js:129:41)
    at executeCallback (D:\DESARROLLO\menuon-project\be-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:397:17)
    at handleCallback (D:\DESARROLLO\menuon-project\be-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:128:55)
    at executeCommand (D:\DESARROLLO\menuon-project\be-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\collection_ops.js:558:12)
    at handleCallback (D:\DESARROLLO\menuon-project\be-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:128:55)
    at db.s.topology.command (D:\DESARROLLO\menuon-project\be-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\db_ops.js:516:5)
    at D:\DESARROLLO\menuon-project\be-server\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:532:18
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at D:\DESARROLLO\menuon-project\be-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4692:13
    at model.Query.Query._completeOne (D:\DESARROLLO\menuon-project\be-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1932:12)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-mongo-registration-login-api@1.0.0 start: `node ./server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-mongo-registration-login-api@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Franco\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-10T16_55_39_844Z-debug.log
```

Comment: First, there's a missing quote at `console.log('not found);`. And the error is being thrown by `throw new Error('example')`, because `!doc` is true and it enters the `if` condition.

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros in the findOneAndUpdate there is acallback when the object was not found ?